# Analysing the runtime efficiency of a Haskell function

Tags: performance, haskell, optimization

I have the following solution in Haskell to [Problem 3](http://projecteuler.net/problem=3):

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime p = (divisors p) == [1, p]

divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors n = [d | d <- [1..n], n `mod` d == 0]

main = print (head (filter isPrime (filter ((==0) . (n `mod`)) [n-1,n-2..])))
  where n = 600851475143
```

However, it takes more than the minute limit given by Project Euler. So how do I analyze the time complexity of my code to determine where I need to make changes?

**Note:** Please do **not** post alternative algorithms. I want to figure those out on my own. For now I just want to analyse the code I have and look for ways to improve it. Thanks!

Comment: A good reference to code profiling/optimization is here: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html.  But, I would rethink the algorithm you're using before diving into that.

Comment: @jtobin By "runtime efficiency," I am thinking at the theoretical level using big-O notation. I can do this type of analysis with impertive languages. I'm quite new to functional languages, so this type of analysis is tricky for me. "Rethinking my algorithm" is exactly what I have in mind by doing this.

Comment: The net problem with all the answers is that they do not get to the result that any such brute force code to do prime factorization, while it may represent a "computational method" that would get to a solution ... it will NOT do so in any reasonable time and power consumption. This isn't a "code" problem, it is "how do I develop a better algorithm or a "near algorithm" (one that often produces an answer more quickly, but may not.  See research on prime factorization..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start from the top.

```
divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors n = [d | d <- [1..n], n `mod` d == 0]
```

For now, let's assume that certain things are cheap: incrementing numbers is O(1), doing `mod` operations is O(1), and comparisons with `0` are O(1). (These are false assumptions, but what the heck.) The `divisors` function loops over all numbers from `1` to `n`, and does an O(1) operation on each number, so computing the complete output is O(n). Notice that here when we say O(n), n is the *input number*, not the *size* of the input! Since it takes m=log(n) bits to store n, this function takes O(2^m) time in the size of the input to produce a complete answer. I'll use n and m consistently to mean the input number and input size below.

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime p = (divisors p) == [1, p]
```

In the worst case, `p` is prime, which forces `divisors` to produce its whole output. Comparison to a list of statically-known length is O(1), so this is dominated by the call to `divisors`. O(n), O(2^m)

Your `main` function does a bunch of things at once, so let's break down subexpressions a bit.

```
filter ((==0) . (n `mod`))
```

This loops over a list, and does an O(1) operation on each element. This is O(m), where here m is the length of the input list.

```
filter isPrime
```

Loops over a list, doing O(n) work on each element, where here n is the largest number in the list. If the list happens to be n elements long (as it is in your case), this means this is O(n*n) work, or O(2^m*2^m) = O(4^m) work (as above, this analysis is for the case where it produces its entire list).

```
print . head
```

Tiny bits of work. Let's call it O(m) for the printing part.

```
main = print (head (filter isPrime (filter ((==0) . (n `mod`)) [n-1,n-2..])))
```

Considering all the subexpressions above, the `filter isPrime` bit is clearly the dominating factor. O(4^m), O(n^2)

Now, there's one final subtlety to consider: throughout the analysis above, I've consistently made the assumption that each function/subexpression was forced to produce its entire output. As we can see in `main`, this probably isn't true: we call `head`, which only forces a little bit of the list. However, if the input number itself isn't prime, we know for sure that we must look through at least half the list: there will certainly be no divisors between `n/2` and `n`. So, at best, we cut our work in half -- which has no effect on the asymptotic cost.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. This is the kind of complexity analysis I was asking for, even if I didn't use those exact words.

Answer (score 11):

Two things:

1. Any time you see a list comprehension (as you have in `divisors`), or equivalently, some series of `map` and/or `filter` functions over a list (as you have in `main`), treat its complexity as Θ(n) just the same as you would treat a `for`-loop in an imperative language.
2. This is probably not quite the sort of advice you were expecting, but I hope it will be *more* helpful: Part of the purpose of Project Euler is to encourage you to think about the definitions of various mathematical concepts, *and* about the many different algorithms that might correctly satisfy those definitions.

Okay, that second suggestion was a bit too nebulous... What I mean is, for example, the way you've implemented `isPrime` is really a textbook definition:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime p = (divisors p) == [1, p]
-- p is prime if its only divisors are 1 and p.
```

Likewise, your implementation of `divisors` is straightforward:

```
divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors n = [d | d <- [1..n], n `mod` d == 0]
-- the divisors of n are the numbers between 1 and n that divide evenly into n.
```

These definitions both read very nicely! Algorithmically, on the other hand, they are too naïve. Let's take a simple example: what are the divisors of the number 10? `[1, 2, 5, 10]`. On inspection, you probably notice a couple things:

- 1 and 10 are pairs, and 2 and 5 are pairs.
- Aside from 10 itself, there can't be any divisors of 10 that are greater than 5.

You can probably exploit properties like these to optimize your algorithm, right? So, without looking at your code -- just using pencil and paper -- try sketching out a faster algorithm for `divisors`. If you've understood my hint, `divisors n` should run in `sqrt n` time. You'll find more opportunities along these lines as you continue. You might decide to redefine everything differently, in a way that doesn't use your `divisors` function at all...

Hope this helps give you the right mindset for tackling these problems!

Comment: The funny thing is I was thinking about just this thing right after I woke up this morning. If I were coding a for loop in C/C++/Java to test for primality, I would stop at sqrt n. Now I just need to figure out how to do that same thing in Haskell. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @Code-Guru The simplest thing would be to use `takeWhile (\k -> k*k <= n) [1 .. ]`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I wasn't asking how to do it =p

Answer (score 2):

[Daniel Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661927/1011995) explains the general strategy of deriving bounds for the runtime complexity rather well. However, as is usually the case for general strategies, it yields too conservative bounds.

So, just for the heck of it, let's investigate this example in some more detail.

```
main = print (head (filter isPrime (filter ((==0) . (n `mod`)) [n-1,n-2..])))
    where n = 600851475143
```

(Aside: if `n` were prime, this would cause a runtime error when checking `` n `mod` 0 == 0 ``, thus I change the list to `[n, n-1 .. 2]` so that the algorithm works for all `n > 1`.)

Let's split up the expression into its parts, so we can see and analyse each part more easily

```
main = print answer
  where
    n = 600851475143
    candidates = [n, n-1 .. 2]
    divisorsOfN = filter ((== 0) . (n `mod`)) candidates
    primeDivisors = filter isPrime divisorsOfN
    answer = head primeDivisors
```

Like Daniel, I work with the assumption that arithmetic operations, comparisons etc. are O(1) - although not true, that's a good enough approximation for all remotely reasonable inputs.

So, of the list `candidates`, the elements from `n` down to `answer` have to be generated, `n - answer + 1` elements, for a total cost of `O(n - answer + 1)`. For composite `n`, we have `answer <= n/2`, then that's Θ(n).

Generating the list of divisors as far as needed is then `Θ(n - answer + 1)` too.

For the number `d(n)` of divisors of `n`, we can use the coarse estimate `d(n) <= 2√n`.

All divisors `>= answer` of `n` have to be checked for primality, that's at least half of all divisors.
Since the list of divisors is lazily generated, the complexity of

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime p = (divisors p) == [1, p]
```

is O(smallest prime factor of p), because as soon as the first divisor `> 1` is found, the equality test is determined. For composite `p`, the smallest prime factor is `<= √p`.

We have `< 2√n` primality checks of complexity at worst O(√n), and one check of complexity `Θ(answer)`, so the combined work of all prime tests carried out is O(n).

Summing up, the total work needed is `O(n)`, since the cost of each step is `O(n)` at worst.

In fact, the total work done in this algorithm is `Θ(n)`. If `n` is prime, generating the list of divisors as far as needed is done in O(1), but the prime test is `Θ(n)`. If `n` is composite, `answer <= n/2`, and generating the list of divisors as far as needed is `Θ(n)`.

If we don't consider the arithmetic operations to be O(1), we have to multiply with the complexity of an arithmetic operation on numbers the size of `n`, that is `O(log n)` bits, which, depending on the algorithms used, usually gives a factor slightly above `log n` and below `(log n)^2`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. This is the kind of complexity analysis I was asking for, even if I didn't use those exact words.